# Tcpdump on openwrt

Tags: tcpdump, openwrt

I'm looking for a tcpdump binary that runs on openwrt. The website only shows source code that must be built. Anybody point me to a location that contains a prebuild binary? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You find binaries at
http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/

but you have to use the right one for your hardware plattform

e.g for x86
http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/x86/packages/tcpdump_4.2.1-1_x86.ipk

The prefered method is to use opkg to install the package

Answer (score 14):

I suggest to set up a working repository, i.e.:

```
https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05-rc2/x86/generic/packages/base/
```

You can put the url on your OpenWRT system under `/etc/opkg.conf`.
Using `opkg` you do not have to deal with all the dependencies.

```
opkg update
opkg install tcpdump
```

If there is no internet connection on the Openwrt system, and there is no local repository deployed, the solution above works as well, but it is more painful and consumes more time.